# How to access controls in Site.Master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a Site.Master page and folders with individual "projects" that each have their own Master page, as well as the detail page:

```
~/Site.Master
       myProject/Project1.Master
       myProject/Project1.aspx
       myProject/Project1.cs
```

I want to use `FindControl()` in `Project1.cs` to find a label that's in `Site.Master`.

I've tried `this.Master.Master`, but it returns null

I've tried `Page.Master` or `this.Master` but that refers to `Project1.Master`

I've tried `Page.Parent.Master` but that also returns null.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The `Site.Master` page has this directive...

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site"  %>
```

The `Project1.master` file has these ...

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TradeEduTeams.master.cs" Inherits="TET_system" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The header of Project1.master ...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Trade Education Teams System (TETs)</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolderHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
...
...
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is my Site.Master page in full...

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site"  %>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Mitec</title>
</head>
<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr valign="top" align="center" >
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Tec-NQ-RGB-218x90.jpg" />
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/mitec.jpg" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:LoginName Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="1.2em" ID="LoginName1" FormatString="login: {0}"
                                    CssClass="loginname" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Tec-NQ-RGB-218x90.jpg" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="3">
              <table>
               <tr>
                <td style="width:20%" valign="top">
                    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" ImageSet="Arrows" ExpandDepth="1" OnTreeNodeDataBound="TreeNode_DataBound" OnDataBound="Tree_DataBound"
                        OnTreeNodeExpanded="TreeNode_Expanded" OnTreeNodeCollapsed="TreeNode_Collapsed" LineImagesFolder="~/TreeLineImages" ShowLines="True">
                        <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                        <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
                        <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" HorizontalPadding="0px"
                            VerticalPadding="0px" />
                        <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="5px"
                            NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                    </asp:TreeView>
                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
                    <div class="menu">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:60%" colspan="2" valign="top">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 3**

I think I know what's going on. The `Site.master` file can have HTML tags, but *not the nested Master file*! The nested master page has to reference **Content placeholders** only, so that it does not clash with the "higher up" tags in the site.master file. Yes?

Comment: Does Project1.Master implement Site.Master or is it a stand alone master page ?

Comment: @JuniorJohn Hi. No. It's just like I drew it. Site.Master is the overall master page for the entire website. Project1.Master is a master page for Project1 which is a subfolder in the website. Site.Master is in the root folder, Project1 is a subfolder. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you add the header of Project1.Master in description please?

Comment: @JuniorJohn I've updated the page

Comment: Project1.Master and Site.Master are two seperate pages. I dont beleive you can access controls of each others. When you create a new master page you have the option to link it to another master page, if you do so this will allow you to access controls using FindControl you tried.

Comment: @JuniorJohn, I've added <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.master" %> on Project1.master, but it still won't work. The only way to get this to work is for me to move the controls out of Site.Master into Project1.master and then I can use Page.Master.FindControl() to find them. Page.Master.Master returns NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please check the example below, i have created a BasicView Master page which includes the main view and i have included a Nested Master page which include some extra controls.. As you can see the ContentPlaceHolder1 in BasicView.master will be replaced with all html code that is inside ContentPlaceHolder1 in ExtraNested.master
This is how you reference and connect 2 master pages with each others..

BasicVew.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BasicView.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.BasicView" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

ExtraNested.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/BasicView.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ExtraNested.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.ExtraNested" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

So now inside ExtraNested.master on Button1.click event you may try to find control textbox of BasicView.master using your code.

NB: BasicView have most of HTML code and ExtraNested used BasicView html with addition to some extra html that it includes.

Comment: Yeah my Update3 was spot on and you've confirmed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're looking for the MasterType directive.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx

Basically, you put the MasterType directive on your child master pages and reference Site.master using it.

Comment: Thanks. I've read that article but I still do not understand how I can jump from an aspx page under a MasterPage, which has an even "higher order" MasterPage (SiteMaster). Do I have to reference first the ContentPlaceholder *then* the MasterPage? In my case my code is inside a form tag, not a ContentPlaceHolder.

Comment: I know about the MasterType, however, how do I find my controls on the Site.Master page? The example on the MS page is misleading. There is not Master.FindControl(). I have to be more specific, like Page.Master.FindControl(), but that refers to Project1.master, not SiteMaster.

Comment: I've added another Update2 showing my Site.master in full. See no ContentPlaceHolder. I surely shouldn't have to put one in there?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand this: does project1.master reference site.master or does it not? Your original post made it sound as though it did.